# change a decision

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for when an important decision is re-thought through and the conclusion is changed ?

E.g.

> I didn't expect you to retroactively ______ the <s>decision</s> (turns out this was the wrong noun too)

I guess in this case it can be synonymous with veto.

I think the word I am looking for starts with "re", like rebuke or refute etc. but it just means to re-decide. Something like revoke.

Comment: Reopen? Revisit? Reconsider? These can all be used when the decision-maker just goes back over the decision, without necessarily coming to a different conclusion, although *reconsider* is often used when a different conclusion is reached. Otherwise, what's wrong with *I didn't expect you to change your mind* or *I thought your original decision was final*. I don't think you want *retroactively*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it would be **rescind**.

Meaning: revoke, cancel, or repeal (a law, order, or agreement)

Ex. *The government eventually rescinded the directive.*

Ref link [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=rescind%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN815IN816&oq=rescind%20meaning&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.3914j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the word is **retract.** It is synonymous to revoke or withdraw or annul etc.

Oxford Dictionary: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retract

> Withdraw or go back on (an undertaking)
>
> > "the parish council was forced to retract a previous resolution."

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend

***TO AMEND***

: to change or modify (something) for the better 
:IMPROVE

([Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amend) )

Comment: the word I think exists that I'm thinking of doesn't necessarily have this positive connotation

Comment: Retract? Rescind? Revise?